# How does 'NowListening' triggers iOS5 banners + delegates?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uilocalnotification, cydia

Essentially a Cydia application that shows an iOS5 notification center banner each time a song changes in the iPod app.

You can:
- Tap the banner to open iPod app
- Tap and hold a banner to show playing controls in the multitasking switcher.
- Swipe a banner to the right to play the next track.

Demo: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ajPdXcJkjs

Is this done with a UILocalNotification at time now-1 or any other method?
How does it not show up in notification center?
How does it do those actions on the notification bar?

Note: I'm asking this to develop a JB app, so no interest in official API's only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the dev of NowListening !

NowListening doesn't provide real notifications, it just provide a banner each time the song changes (with any app) ;)
So, to do this, you have to create an instance of BBBulletin and push it to SBBulletinBannerController.
To dump all these classes, use class-dump.

Comment: Hi McNight, SBBulletinBannerController seems to be modified by APPLE in iOS6. Have you figured out how this work on iOS6?